# How to upgrade Rails session format/encryption with rolling releases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, encryption, cookies, upgrade

We would like to upgrade our Rails session cookies from Marshal to JSON and we need to switch from signed to encrypted sessions. From what we could see Rails only supports upgrades with read-only compatibility on the release itself. So for example, for `:hybrid` session serialization format:

- Releases having `:hybrid` will convert read Marshal-encoded sessions and convert them to JSON, and will create new sessions in JSON
- Releases still having `:marshal` will fail to decode JSON sessions and will discard them, killing the user's session

Somewhat comparable situation with encrypted cookies

- Releases having `secret_key_base` set will apply session cookie encryption, and it seems they will be able to read the signed sessions but will convert them into encrypted sessions
- Releases not having `secret_key_base` will fail to decode encrypted cookies at all and will discard them, killing the user's session

The problem for us comes from doing rolling releases - we can't guarantee all requests will be hitting *only* servers having either one of these set. And given Rails' "shared nothing" approach we do not have session affinity on the fronting load balancer/proxy, so we are unable to ensure sessions in "new" formats will hit the "new" releases only. For users who already have sessions, this will mean they will be forcibly logged out if they end up on an older release with a "new-style" session cookie.

So far I have thought about a few possible scenarios:

- Do a hard-switchover release. Very hard in our setup
- Patch the relevant session serialization mechanisms to permit reading "new-style" data without writing it (ouch, this is a lot of very critical code to get right and it is all monkey-patches)
- Write our own session serializer that we then have to support until the heat death of the universe
- Never upgrade anything?...

I wonder if I maybe missed some alternatives.

Comment: It seems like there is a missing option: a serializer that will read both marshal and json but write using `marshal`.

Then you could deploy with this serializer first, then deploy with the `:hybrid` serializer, and then, when all unconverted marshal cookies will have expired, deploy with the `json` serializer.

Comment: @DerekKraan making a custom serializer can indeed be an option for the serialization format. But no solution yet for the encrypted/signed downgrade.